# Резиновый слайдер с фиксированной высотой?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Собственно нужен резиновый слайдер с фиксированной высотой или просто совет, как добиться этого на примере любого слайдера.
Буду очень благодарен. Использовал responsiveslides.com и Flexslider

Comment: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: спасибо, но это не решило моей проблемы. мне нужен адаптивный по ширине слайдер чтобы не превышал фиксированную высоту

Comment: Ну так настройте его как Вам нужно. А вообще любой слайдер можно адаптировать при желании.

Answer (score 1):

Используете любой слайдер, например responsiveslides.com.
Как элемент слайдера используете div у которого картинка задана фоном

```
background: url(1.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
height: 500px;
width: 100%;
```

Тогда у вас будет адаптивный слайдер с фиксированной высотой

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы картинки грузились из кода (верстка будет натянута на движок и нужно чтобы они менялись вручную пользователем).

Comment: Используйте инлайновые стили картинки для дива и пользователи смогут их редактировать.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```js
$('.sl-img').each(function(){
  var path = $(this).attr('src');
  var d = $(this).closest('div');
  
  d.css({
    'background': 'url(' + path + ') center no-repeat',
    '-webkit-background-size': 'cover',
    'background-size': 'cover'
  });
});

$('.slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 500,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
      }
    }
    ]
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  padding: .25rem;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.slider {
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
  position: relative;
}

.slider div {
  height: 200px;
}

.slider div img {
  display: none;
}

.slick-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.slick-next {
  left: 7rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="slider">
    <div><div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/b8b8b8/fff.png" alt="" class="sl-img"></div></div>
    <div><div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/900x300/b8b8b8/fff.png" alt="" class="sl-img"></div></div>
    <div><div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/750x450/b8b8b8/fff.png" alt="" class="sl-img"></div></div>
    <div><div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/850x350/b8b8b8/fff.png" alt="" class="sl-img"></div></div>
    <div><div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x480/b8b8b8/fff.png" alt="" class="sl-img"></div></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Пример на jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wotemu/edit?html,js,output)

Используемый плагин - [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)